# yocto IMAGE_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-dunfell

I am facing an issue with my meta layer where after building the image i am using a function to move the rootfs and bootloader files to a custom created folder in the build directory bootloader files are being moved easly but the ${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.tar not being copied becuase the function is trying to copy the tar file before its being packaged. can anyone provide any workaround on this.
FYI the yocto version iam using is dunfell

```
require path/to/shell/script

IMAGE_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "function;"
```

The function should only run after packaging of the rootfs.